# Tensorflow padding in map function

Tags: python, tensorflow

I currently have a dataset of `n`x`m` tensors that I need to pad to `13`x`m` tensor (`n <= 13`); however, I cannot figure out how to do this without Tensorflow losing the shape of my tensor.

I am trying to apply the `map` function to these, but `tf.constant` cannot accept a tensor as part of the padding specification and because of `map`'s requirement I cannot just use the `numpy` method.

```
def pad_tensor(x):
    current_length = tf.shape(x)[0]
    additional_length = 13 - current_length
        
    padding = tf.constant([[0, additional_length], [0, 0]])
    return tf.pad(x, padding, "CONSTANT")
```

I know I can use `py_func` but when I do that, tensorflow loses the shape of the data in the dataset.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

PS: I'm not sure exactly what you mean by *apply the map function to these* and *because of map's requirement I cannot just use the numpy method*, if you still have problem after following example then please make the definition of the problem more clear

FWIW, add `.numpy()` and code running without any error:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

def pad_tensor(x):
    current_length = tf.shape(x)[0]
    additional_length = 13 - current_length.numpy()
    padding = tf.constant([[0, additional_length], [0, 0]])
    return tf.pad(x, padding, "CONSTANT")

n = 3
m = 5
x = tf.constant(np.random.rand(n, m))
pad_tensor(x)
```

Outputs:

```
<tf.Tensor: shape=(13, 5), dtype=float64, numpy=
array([[0.35710346, 0.49611589, 0.18744049, 0.91046784, 0.19934265],
       [0.51464596, 0.96416921, 0.87008494, 0.52756893, 0.23010099],
       [0.05335277, 0.88451633, 0.25949178, 0.91156944, 0.03638372],
       [0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ],
       [0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ],
       [0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ],
       [0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ],
       [0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ],
       [0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ],
       [0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ],
       [0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ],
       [0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ],
       [0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ]])>
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm `map`ing onto a dataset, so `numpy()` isn't allowed